# Does Eclipse sometimes display incorrect deprecation warnings?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been looking on the web and the only thing I have found is some bugs which may not be real bugs. The question is quite clear from the title. Is there a known issue whether or not the deprecation warnings in Eclipse may be incorrect? I one example is the `rectangleBuilder` from `javafx.scene.shape`. The class is classified as deprecated in Eclipse, but There is no hint to this in Oracles deprecation list or in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Eclipse does not usually get this wrong.

RectangleBuilder is marked as deprecated in the JavaFX source:

```java
/**
Builder class for javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
@see javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle
@deprecated This class is deprecated and will be removed in the next version
* @since JavaFX 2.0
*/
@javax.annotation.Generated("Generated by javafx.builder.processor.BuilderProcessor")
@Deprecated
public class RectangleBuilder<B extends javafx.scene.shape.RectangleBuilder<B>> extends javafx.scene.shape.ShapeBuilder<B> implements javafx.util.Builder<javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle> {
```

Comment: Ok, this means Eclipse has got it right. It is just annoying there are no documentation regarding this. Seems as if Oracle tries to do serious promotion for JavaFX. Just annoying they are not following up all details about it. It would be better to do a proper  launch of the API, instead of only tons of promotion. However, regarding the comment it seems as any way would be better though...

Comment: The most serious flaw I see here is deprecating a class with no hint of a replacement or recommended migration strategy.

Comment: @StephanHerrmann I completely agree, this is not the only issues with JavaFX though. Before starting up a project you need to go through a number of rituals in eclipse just to be able to access the JavaFX libraries. This is eclipse though and this may not be the case for other IDEs/compilers.

Comment: @patrik ar you using e(fx)clipse? I know that Tom Schindl is jumping through hoops to make that setup easier for Eclipse users.